# Express JS Json Return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

I am attempting to make a simple AngularJS application that will pull from a RESTful API to fill out some "cards" on the screen.

Here is my Angular $http request (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is to hide my public IP):

```
$http({method : "GET", url : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/api/cards"}).then(function mySucces(response) {$scope.listData = response.data;});
```

This request works for actual JSON formatted calls, such as a call to http://data.consumerfinance.gov/api/views.json - it works great here.

However, it does not work when calling my RESTful API created with node-restful using nodejs. I can view the API data in the web browser, but I cannot get it to pull in the angular app. I am about 99.99% sure it is because I am not returning it as JSON format but mongodb format from my API.

I am asking for assistance to find a way to have my RESTful API return JSON formatting.

Here is my server.js:

```
// Dependencies

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var parth = require('path');

// Connect to Mongoose (MongoDB)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test')


// Build Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Router
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));


// Start Server

app.listen(9000)
console.log('Yo, stuffs on port 9000')
```

Here is my routes.js:

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();

// Models
var Card = require('../models/cards')

// Routes
Card.methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
Card.register(router, '/cards')

// Return Router

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my mongoose schema (cards.js):

```
// Dependencies
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

// Schema
var cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    desc: String,
    cardtype: String
});


// Return model
module.exports = restful.model('Cards', cardSchema);
```

One of my issues is that I do not know where I need to but the function(res, resp, next) in, which file and what should it look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is responding in JSON - I validated on jslint. Ignore me here, the problem is with the angular app then.

Answer (score 0):

I Wiresharked it. It is totally sending JSON back. This is an issue with the application for whichever reason.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your server.js file simple put this code.

```
`var logger= function (req, res, next) {
```

console.log('LOGGED');
  next();
}; app.use(logger);`